# way to find the List of all ids in a list of entities from inner object with java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have an entity:

```
public class Entity
{
    private long id;    
    private InnerEnity data;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public InnerEnity getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

InnerEnity class

```
public class InnerEnity 
{
    private long id;    
    private String data;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

what i need is list of InnerEnity ids. 
TO resolve this i tried something like that :-

> List innerEnityIds = listOfEnity.stream().map(sys -> sys.getData().stream().map(obj->obj.getId().collect(Collectors.toList())));

Comment: how about this `List<Long> ids = entity.stream().map(Entity::getData).map(InnerEnity::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to `map` the `entity` to its inner entity's(`data`) `id` as :

```
List<Long> innerEnityIds = listOfEnity.stream()
        .map(entity -> entity.getData().getId()) // <<< this
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler than what you tried. Since each `Entity` contains a single `InnerEnity`, which contains a single `long` identifier, you only need a simple `map`:

```
List<Long> innerEnityIds = 
    listOfEnity.stream()
               .map(sys -> sys.getData().getId())
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```